# Custom GUI template script creator

Tags: objective-c, templates, user-interface, plist

My app currently reads a script containing instructions on what the app should do next. Think of it this way ---> My app is like an orchestra, and when it is passed sheet music (the script), it knows what to do. The sheet defines what different parts of the orchestra do at different times.

Currently, writing the script by hand is tedious. I want to be able to define chunks, which I can drag and drop from my gui to the script. I was wondering if there already is tools which let you do something like this, or if I should write my own tool.

Basically, when I click on something in the gui, it should insert a template into my plist, which I can tweak.

EDIT: It looks like the ability to create "Property list Structure Definitions" is what I am after. I have tried searching the apple site, but I can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind:

1. You don't mention what format the input is in, nor what you want the GUI tool to do beyond letting you "drag chunks". But **if you can define your format into an XML schema, then you can use any number of XML authoring tools** that customize their interface based on schema. Also gives you the ability to make it easy to let the UI enter parameters/customization, which your script language likely has. Final bonus: you might be able to convert script directly into a plist with a simple XSLT file.
2. Check out [Briefs](http://giveabrief.com/), which is a prototyping application for iOS apps that has a similar architecture.

Comment: I don't need the GUI to do anything beyond letting my drag chunks into the plist and save it. What I want is something that lets me create a template like the info.plist in Xcode, which lets me define custom fields with default values within the plist. This would save me a lot of time, and prevent errors that could occur if I had to do a lot of the typing manually.